# How can I make YouTube loop a video over and over?

Tags: youtube

I'm looking for a way to have YouTube videos loop over and over without having to build playlists and or needing the use of extensions or other plugins.

How can I loop YouTube videos naturally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way?  Right click twice in the video.

If you right click the video you'll be greeted with a list of options for the HTML5 player, seen below:

[image]

However, should you right click once again, you will see a second menu.

[image]

Within this menu is a toggle for "Loop" which prompts the video to autoloop once it has finished playing.  This was tested on both the Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer Browser, and it worked on all 3 browsers. It doesn't require the use of extensions/plugins, or making a playlist then looping it.